# How to optimise the mysql 5.5 stored procedure

Tags: mysql, join, stored-procedures, query-optimization

Hi we are using the below SP , its taking more 100% CPU utilization , takes long time to execute the SP,
How to improve this Stored Procedure

This procedure have many joins and inner Joins

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `get_tp`(
IN loggedInUser varchar(100),IN mName varchar(100),
IN meName varchar(200), IN deviceType varchar(50),
IN deviceName varchar(50),IN pS varchar(100),
IN lp varchar(100), IN segtype varchar(100),
IN PT varchar(100), IN CID varchar(50),
IN FID varchar(50), IN clliCodeIn varchar(500),
IN startIndex INT, IN endIndex INT,
IN columnindex INT, IN sortorder INT,
OUT rowcount INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE ccount INT;
DECLARE ecount INT;
DECLARE mcount1 INT;
DECLARE mcount2 INT;
DECLARE MTID INT;
IF startIndex IS NULL THEN
  SET startIndex = 0;
END IF;
IF endIndex IS NULL THEN
  SET endIndex  = 10;
END IF;
IF meName IS NULL THEN
  set meName = '';
END IF;
IF pS IS NULL THEN
  set pS = '%';
END IF;
IF PT IS NULL THEN
  set PT = '';
END IF;
IF deviceName IS NULL THEN
  set deviceName = '%';
END IF;
IF lp IS NULL THEN
  set lp = '%';
END IF;
IF deviceType IS NULL THEN
  set deviceType = '%';
END IF;
IF FID IS NULL || FID = '' THEN
    set FID = '%';
ELSE
  set FID = CONCAT('%',FID,'%');
END IF;
IF clliCodeIn IS NULL OR '' THEN
  SET clliCodeIn = '%';
END IF;
SELECT id INTO MTID from m_desc where m_name =mName;
SET segtype = '%';
  SELECT distinct me.elementName, tp.elementName, dtp.device_type, dtp.device_name,
         tpt.maxBw,IF(STRCMP(tpt.CKT_used,'null'),tpt.CKT_used,'0'),
         IF(STRCMP(tpt.CKT_res,'null'),tpt.CKT_res,'0'),
         IF(STRCMP(tpt.PKT_use,'null'),tpt.PKT_use,'0'),
         IF(STRCMP(tpt.packet_reservedbw,'null'),tpt.PKT_res,'0'),tp.type,
         G_M_E_T(me.elementName) as segmentType,             tpt.niType,dtp.id,get_derived_managed_element_type(me.elementName),mtc.cllicode
  FROM metro_detail md
  INNER JOIN me1 me ON md.node_clli = me.elementName
  INNER JOIN t_p1 tp ON tp.id_M_Ele = me.id_M_Ele
  INNER JOIN esystem ON esystem.idesystem = me.idesystem and esystem.type LIKE CONCAT(segtype)
  LEFT JOIN t_p_a tpt ON tp.elementName = tpt.tpName AND me.elementName = tpt.neName
  LEFT OUTER JOIN d_t_m dtp ON dtp.me1 = me.elementName AND dtp.ter_pt = tp.elementName
  LEFT JOIN m_e_tp_cl mtc ON (mtc.idChassis = tp.chassisId AND mtc.idm_e_tp_cl = tp.id_M_Ele)
  WHERE tpt.maxBW > 0 AND
        tpt.provisionableState = 1 AND
        CONCAT(me.elementName,tp.elementName) NOT IN (SELECT CONCAT(exit_node,exit_node_tp)
                                                          FROM m_tp_i
                                                          WHERE met_id = MTID) AND
        CONCAT(me.elementName,tp.elementName) NOT IN (SELECT CONCAT(entry_node,entry_node_tp)
                                                          FROM m_tp_i
                                                          WHERE met_id = MTID) AND
        CONCAT(me.elementName,tp.elementName) NOT IN (SELECT CONCAT(a_ne_m1,a_end_m1)
                                                          FROM e_s
                                                          WHERE product = 'PROD_H') AND
        CONCAT(tp.elementName,me.elementName) NOT IN (SELECT CONCAT(ev.a_end, ev.a_ne)
                                                          FROM e_seg ev
                                                          INNER JOIN e_s e ON e.CirID=ev.CirID
                                                          WHERE tpt.niType = "TP_U" AND e.cust_id!=CID) AND
        CONCAT(tp.elementName,me.elementName) NOT IN (SELECT CONCAT(ev.z_end, ev.z_ne)
                                                          FROM e_seg ev
                                                          INNER JOIN e_s e ON e.CirID=ev.CirID
                                                          WHERE tpt.niType = "TP_U" and e.cust_id!=CID) AND
        md.met_id = MTID AND
        tp.type != 'TPT_CTP' AND
        me.elementName COLLATE latin1_general_cs LIKE CONCAT('%',meName,'%') AND
        tpt.maxBw COLLATE latin1_general_cs LIKE CONCAT(pS) AND
        tpt.niType COLLATE latin1_general_cs LIKE CONCAT ('%',PT,'%') AND
        tp.type COLLATE latin1_general_cs LIKE CONCAT(lp) AND
        IF(STRCMP(deviceName,'%'),dtp.device_name COLLATE latin1_general_cs
              LIKE CONCAT(deviceName),dtp.device_name IS NULL OR dtp.device_name IS NOT NULL) AND
        IF(STRCMP(deviceType,'%'),dtp.device_type COLLATE latin1_general_cs
              LIKE CONCAT(deviceType),dtp.device_type IS NULL OR dtp.device_type IS NOT NULL) AND
        IF(STRCMP(FID,'%'),dtp.id COLLATE latin1_general_cs
              LIKE CONCAT(FID),dtp.id IS NULL OR dtp.id IS NOT NULL) AND
        IF(STRCMP(clliCodeIn,'%'),mtc.cllicode COLLATE latin1_general_cs
              LIKE CONCAT('%',clliCodeIn,'%'),mtc.cllicode IS NULL OR mtc.cllicode IS NOT NULL)
   ORDER BY tpt.niType DESC, me.elementName 
   LIMIT startIndex, endIndex;


   SELECT count(*) INTO rowcount
   FROM metro_detail md
   INNER JOIN me1 me ON md.node_clli = me.elementName
   INNER JOIN t_p1 tp ON tp.id_M_Ele = me.id_M_Ele
   INNER JOIN esystem ON esystem.idesystem = me.idesystem AND esystem.type LIKE CONCAT(segtype)
   LEFT JOIN t_p_a tpt ON tp.elementName = tpt.tpName AND me.elementName = tpt.neName
   LEFT OUTER JOIN d_t_m dtp ON dtp.me1 = me.elementName AND dtp.ter_pt = tp.elementName
   LEFT JOIN m_e_tp_cl mtc ON (mtc.idChassis = tp.chassisId AND mtc.idm_e_tp_cl = tp.id_M_Ele)
   WHERE tpt.maxBW > 0 AND
         tpt.provisionableState = 1 AND
         CONCAT(me.elementName,tp.elementName) NOT IN (SELECT CONCAT(exit_node,exit_node_tp)
                                                           FROM m_tp_i
                                                           WHERE met_id = MTID) AND
         CONCAT(me.elementName,tp.elementName) NOT IN (SELECT CONCAT(entry_node,entry_node_tp)
                                                           FROM m_tp_i
                                                           WHERE met_id = MTID) AND
         CONCAT(me.elementName,tp.elementName) NOT IN (SELECT CONCAT(a_ne_m1,a_end_m1)
                                                           FROM e_s
                                                           WHERE product = 'PROD_H') AND
         CONCAT(tp.elementName,me.elementName) NOT IN (SELECT CONCAT(ev.a_end, ev.a_ne)
                                                           FROM e_seg ev
                                                           INNER JOIN e_s e ON e.CirID=ev.CirID
                                                           WHERE tpt.niType = "TP_U" AND e.cust_id!=CID) AND
         CONCAT(tp.elementName,me.elementName) NOT IN (SELECT CONCAT(ev.z_end, ev.z_ne)
                                                           FROM e_seg ev
                                                           INNER JOIN e_s e ON e.CirID=ev.CirID
                                                           WHERE tpt.niType = "TP_U" AND e.cust_id!=CID) AND
         md.met_id = MTID AND
         tp.type != 'TPT_CTP' AND
         me.elementName COLLATE latin1_general_cs LIKE CONCAT('%',meName,'%') AND
         tpt.maxBw COLLATE latin1_general_cs LIKE CONCAT(pS) AND
         tpt.niType COLLATE latin1_general_cs LIKE CONCAT ('%',PT,'%') AND
         tp.type COLLATE latin1_general_cs LIKE CONCAT(lp) AND
         IF(STRCMP(deviceName,'%'),dtp.device_name COLLATE latin1_general_cs
             LIKE CONCAT(deviceName),dtp.device_name IS NULL OR dtp.device_name IS NOT NULL) AND
         IF(STRCMP(deviceType,'%'),dtp.device_type COLLATE latin1_general_cs
             LIKE CONCAT(deviceType),dtp.device_type IS NULL OR dtp.device_type IS NOT NULL) AND
         IF(STRCMP(FID,'%'),dtp.id COLLATE latin1_general_cs
             LIKE CONCAT(FID),dtp.id IS NULL OR dtp.id IS NOT NULL) AND
         IF(STRCMP(clliCodeIn,'%'),mtc.cllicode COLLATE latin1_general_cs
              LIKE CONCAT('%',clliCodeIn,'%'),mtc.cllicode IS NULL OR mtc.cllicode IS NOT NULL) ;
```

### END

### Table Definition

```
CREATE TABLE `me1` (
  `id_M_Ele` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'idesystem' int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `elementName` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `productName` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_M_Ele`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idesystem_elementName_UNIQUE` (`idesystem`,`elementName`),
  KEY `fk_me_ems` (`idesystem`),
  KEY `index_ME` (`idesystem`,`id_M_Ele`,`elementName`,`productName`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_me_ems` FOREIGN KEY (`idesystem`)
       REFERENCES `esystem` (`idesystem`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=45706 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


CREATE TABLE `t_p1` (
  `idtp` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_M_Ele` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `chassisId` int(11) NOT NULL,  
  `elementName` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ctpName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` enum(''TPT_PTP'',''TPT_CTP'',''TPT_FTP''), 
  `provisionableState` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `niType` enum(''TPT_UNI'',''TPT_NNI'') DEFAULT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`idtp`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_M_Ele_elementName_ctpValue_UNIQUE` (`id_M_Ele`,`elementName`,`ctpName`),
  KEY `fk_tp_me_tp` (`id_M_Ele`),
  KEY `index_TP` (`elementName`,`chassisId`,`id_M_Ele`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tp_me_tp` FOREIGN KEY (`id_M_Ele`)
       REFERENCES `me1` (`id_M_Ele`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) AUTO_INCREMENT=8690591 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


'CREATE TABLE `t_p_a` (
  `idesystem` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `neName` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `tpName` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `provisionableState` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `niType` enum(''TP_U'',''TP_N'') DEFAULT NULL,
  `maxBW` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CKT_use` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CKT_res` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PKT_use` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PKT_res` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,    
  PRIMARY KEY (`idesystem`,`neName`,`tpName`),
  KEY `index_TPA` (`tpName`,`neName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1'

'CREATE TABLE `d_t_m` (
  `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `me1` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `ter_pt` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `device_type` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `device_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `device_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_d_t_m_1` (`device_id`,`device_type`),
  KEY `index_DTP` (`me1`,`ter_pt`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_d_t_m_1` FOREIGN KEY (`device_id`, `device_type`)
       REFERENCES `device_type` (`id`, `device_type`)
       ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC'


CREATE TABLE `m_e_tp_cl` (
  `idm_e_tp_cl` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idChassis` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cllicode` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idm_e_tp_cl`,`idChassis`),
  KEY `fk_id_managed_element` (`idm_e_tp_cl`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_id_managed_element` FOREIGN KEY (`idm_e_tp_cl`)
       REFERENCES `me1` (`id_M_Ele`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


CREATE TABLE `m_tp_i` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `met_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
  `exit_node` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `entry_node` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `exit_node_tp` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `entry_node_tp` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `link_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`link_name`),
  KEY `FK_metro_terminationpoint_info_1` (`met_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_metro_terminationpoint_info_1` FOREIGN KEY (`met_id`)
       REFERENCES `metro_description` (`id`)
       ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC



CREATE TABLE `e_s` (
  `CirID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `bkp_copy` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''0'',
  `last_order_number` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `product` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `cust_id` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL, 
  `a_end_m1` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `z_end_m1` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `a_ne_m1` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `z_ne_m1` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `a_end_m2` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `z_end_m2` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `a_ne_m2` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `z_ne_m2` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CirID`,`bkp_copy`),
  UNIQUE KEY `CirID_index1` (`CirID`,`bkp_copy`),
  KEY `fk_e_s_order` (`last_order_number`),
  KEY `index_en` (`CirID`,`cust_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_e_s_order` FOREIGN KEY (`last_order_number`)
       REFERENCES `order` (`order_number`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 PACK_KEYS=1


CREATE TABLE `e_seg` (
  `CirID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `bkp_copy` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''0'',
  `segmentid` tinyint(4) NOT NULL, 
  `a_end` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `z_end` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `a_ne` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `z_ne` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`CirID`,`bkp_copy`,`segmentid`),
  KEY `fk_e_seg_e_s` (`CirID`,`bkp_copy`),
  KEY `index_ev` (`CirID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_e_seg_e_s` FOREIGN KEY (`CirID`, `bkp_copy`)
       REFERENCES `e_s` (`CirID`, `bkp_copy`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

This sp returns the Count and the value to list in java UI

Comment: Please add your table definitions. Optimizing your query depends mainly on your keys/indexes. And i guess you can get rid of a lot of concats (if e.g. exit_nodes are element names), COLLATEs and maybe a lot of subquery like `not in (select` (if e.g. met_id is a unique key). but as I said, that depends on your table definitions/indexes and data. You also might also want to send the whole result to the client and do the count and the limit there (so you don't need to recall the procedure just for scrolling/changing limits). But this depends on your data (100000 resultrows might be too many).

Comment: And Please, Please, Please: Would you MySql people stop tagging questions with sql-server tags? It's high time you guys realize that they are 2 different products!

Comment: CREATE TABLE `me1` (
  `id_M_Ele` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'idesystem' int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `elementName` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `productName` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_M_Ele`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idesystem_elementName_UNIQUE` (`idesystem`,`elementName`),
  KEY `fk_me_ems` (`idesystem`),
  KEY `index_ME` (`idesystem`,`id_M_Ele`,`elementName`,`productName`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_me_ems` FOREIGN KEY (`idesystem`) REFERENCES `esystem` (`idesystem`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=45706 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Answer (score 1):

How to optimize a Stored Procedure?  Start by testing the pieces to see which one(s) are the slowest.

In this case it is easy to see:  `NOT IN ( SELECT ... )` is very inefficient, at least in older versions of MySQL (including 5.5; 5.6 has some improvement).  Turn them into `LEFT JOIN ... WHERE ... IS NULL`.

And don't compare `CONCATs`, that totally eliminates the change of using any index.  Instead use something like

```
me.elementName = exit_mode AND tp.elementName = exit_node_tp
```

Then have a composite index:

```
INDEX(exit_node, exit_node_tp)
```

Beware of mixing `COUNT(*)` and `JOIN`.  `JOIN` *probably* inflates the number of rows in the intermediate table, then the `COUNT` grabs the inflated count.

`dtp.device_name COLLATE latin1_general_cs` also eliminates the use of an index.  Solution declare `dtp.device_name` with that collation (if possible)?

There are probably several more things to advise on.  Work on the above suggestions, then come back for more advice/abuse.  Include `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for that big `SELECT`.

Comment: updated the Table definition along the procedure.we have auto increment for two table and the table data will be deleted and recreated , but the count is  select count(*) from t_p1; -- 23400  but the (AUTO_INCREMENT=8690591) and select count(*) from me1 ; -- 73 but the AUTO_INCREMENT=45706

Comment: `AUTO_INCREMENT` values are not reused, so it is possible to have that be much higher than the `COUNT(*)`.  Is that the issue?

Comment: What character set and/or collation are you using when you connect to mysql?  What happens if you remove the `COLLATE latin1_general_cs` from the query?